# Internal error occurred during: "Publishing to Oracle WebLogic Server 12c ..."

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have configured WebLogic 12c into Eclipse. If running WebLogic server without project, it's running good. But just created dynamic web project not included any code, it's giving the below error. Please advise what is the reason for the below internal error?

> An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to Oracle WebLogic
>   Server 12c (12.1.1) at localhost [webservices1]...".
>   Could not initialize class oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.facets.WlsGarFacet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known issue in some past versions of Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse. To workaround, install Oracle Coherence Tools from Eclipse Marketplace or just update to the latest version of OEPE (12.1.2.1.1), where this issue was fixed.

Comment: Thanks... Installing Coherence Tools worked perfectly for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse->Market place, search for Oracle Coherence Tools and install it and rerun the dynamic web project. This helps in solving the x issue mentioned above.

See: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://techblogsearch.com/a/how-to-run-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse-using-weblogic.html